# Spark Scala Dataframe union all multiple times

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, union-all

I am trying to find a way to dynamically convert the below dataframe using Spark scala

| id | cnt_wk | wk1 | wk2 | wk3 | wk4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 124 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 223 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 225 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

to this

| id | cnt_wk | num_wks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 1 |
| 124 | 2 | 1 |
| 223 | 3 | 1 |
| 225 | 4 | 1 |
| 124 | 2 | 2 |
| 223 | 3 | 2 |
| 225 | 4 | 2 |
| 223 | 3 | 3 |
| 224 | 4 | 3 |
| 224 | 4 | 4 |

Is there a better way to do this, instead of manually filtering the rows and doing an union all.
Also columns wk1, wk2 ... wkn changes dynamically based on the max(cnt_wk).
Source Data volume is > 200mil

Comment: how do you get the num_wks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stack` to unpivot the table first, and filter the matched week data.

```
data = [
    [123,1,1,0,0,0],
    [124,2,1,1,0,0],
    [223,3,1,1,1,0],
    [225,4,1,1,1,1]
]
cols = ['id','cnt_wk','wk1','wk2','wk3','wk4']
stack_cols = cols[2:]
stack_expr = ', '.join([f"'{c}', {c}" for c in stack_cols])
stack_size = len(stack_cols) + 1

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)

df.selectExpr('id', 'cnt_wk', f'stack({stack_size}, {stack_expr}) as (col_wk, num_wks)') \
  .filter('substr(col_wk, 3, 1) = cnt_wk') \
  .drop('col_wk') \
  .show()

+---+------+-------+
| id|cnt_wk|num_wks|
+---+------+-------+
|123|     1|      1|
|124|     2|      1|
|223|     3|      1|
|225|     4|      1|
+---+------+-------+
```